# Three.js CSS3D Renderer YouTube Issues

Tags: css, three.js, youtube-api

I placed a YouTube video in my three.js app using the CSS3D renderer, you can see a simplified example in the JSFiddle below.

I have 2 issues:

1 - The video goes black at certain angles. Not sure why.

2 - The YouTube API’s div handling is causing problems:

- The YouTube API works by replacing a blank div of your making with an iframe, however the API isn’t disposing of the original div which occludes the the video. (The div is **pink** in the JSFiddle)
- I came up with a hacky solution: set the div width to 0px with jquery. But the presence of this random div is causing performance issues in my app - getting rid of it also gets rid of the YouTube div.
  Any insight on either of these issues would be much appreciated!

HERE IS THE JSFIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/fractalfantasy/ed9fw57x/22/

```
   //THIS IS THE ANNOYING DIV (LINE 32)
   var videodiv = document.createElement('div');
   videodiv.style.width = '480px';
   videodiv.style.height = '360px';
   videodiv.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
   videodiv.setAttribute("id", "videoframe");

   // THIS IS MY AWFUL HACK TO GET RID OF IT (LINE 147)
   $("div #videoframe").css("width", "0px");
   $("div #videoframe").css("height", "0px");
   $("div #videoframe").css("background-color", "yellow");

   $("iframe").css("width", "480px");
   $("iframe").css("height", "360px");
   $("iframe").css("background-color", "black");
```

Comment: It's true that the video goes black at certain angles but only Chrome. However, Firefox and Safari don't show this issue. Tested on macOS. So maybe it's best to report this issue to the Chromium bug tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: Yes so I've found that the black flickering happens because of that random blank div, which is also weirdly causing performance issues. If the div is set to transparent, with no background color the black flickering doesnt happen. Still trying to find a way to fix the performance issues and find a less hacky solution.